# Forward the whole domain of a domain name without hosting

Tags: dns, forwarding, hosting

I am the owner of the domain name http://www.kalisto-decor.be/. I didn't add a hosting to this domain because it just has the purpose to redirect. This domain is set up with a 301 forward to another domain. The redirect goes fine when you enter www.kalisto-decor.be. But when I go to a **subdirectory** of the domain, example http://www.kalisto-decor.be/details.html the page generates a 404 error page. So it doesn't link to the right redirect domain.

I have added this A-record to the DNS-management page: **.kalisto-decor.be/***

What can I do to get every page forwarded to the other domain? I can't add a .htacccess file to the root folder, because there is no hosting on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are asking unless the web provider has provision for it in the web service. DNS (with respect to http protocol) does nothing more then convert a domain into an IP address. This is clearly working.

To be clear  ".kalisto-decor.be/*" is a nonsense in a DNS record, as (for HTTP) there is no DNS mechanism for handling pages. Your DNS provider should not be allowing this kind of entry - it is being ignored.

When negotiating an HTTP(S) request A DNS lookup takes place. The web client then sends a request to the web server. One of the first lines of the request will be something like "GET /details.HTML HTTP/1.1". The second line is something like " Host:  www.calisto-decor.de"- These requests are made by browser without reference to DNS (ie not using the DNS protocol).  As long as the web server is not configured to return a 300 series response ( in this case 301), no redirect can take place.

In other words, you are still using a web server for the redirect, but that server is not configured to handle redirects for URLs.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

After contact with the domain provider, they suggested 2 solutions.
1: Send the traffic with a CNAME-record from kalisto-decor.be to dimk.be. Hereby there will be sent a page en will dimk.be/PAGE been called.

2: In the hostingpackage of dimk.be, create a .htaccess file with the redirect from kalisto-decor.be to the homepage of dimk.be.

I chose solution 1 because the domain name provider could do this for me.

Thanks

Comment: 1 is bad advice. Whoever gave it to you does not properly understand CNAMES. This may have unintended side effects resolving mail and subdomains.

Comment: Indeed. I already had a reply of a collegue of the one who gave the advice, with the notification not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `*.kalisto-decor.be` instead. [Googling I see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) [your domain](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/597/2237/how-can-i-set-up-a-catchall-wildcard-subdomain) [registrar](https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-up-wildcard-dns-3301) may have you put just a * for the hostname and/or have a special button just for this. Seems your registrar may be Totaaldomein, I'd search their site for wild card, I didn't have luck likely because I am trying it in English & that doesn't seem to be the native language on this site

Comment: This is incorrect. The problem has nothing to do with wildcard DNS.